# "weak" and "copy" attributes for property with full custom getter and setter

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am a beginner in Objective-C, so i try to accomplish Apple Exercises from this post: [Apple Objective-C guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW25)

I trying to create class properties with custom getter and setter, one with "weak" attribute, and one with "copy" attribute:

```
@property (weak, getter=getFirstName, setter=setFirstName:) NSString *firstName;
@property (copy, getter=getFirstName, setter=setFirstName:) NSString *secondName;
```

Then, i test these properties like this:

```
NSString *name = @"John";
NSMutableString *surname = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Doe"];
MyPerson *person = [MyPerson createWithFirstName:name secondName:surname];
[person tellName];

name = nil;
[person tellName];
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
[surname appendString:@"dze"];
[person tellName];
```

So I expect then after name set to nil, weak property also became a nil; and property marked as "copy" will handle their own copy of initial string, and appending some values to initial strings wouldn't cause any consequences in MyPerson object. But, when i call log methods, i have original value for firstName and changed value in secondName, just like there is no "weak" and "copy" attributes.

This is a log what i gor:

> First name: John; Second name: Doe; BirthDate: (null)
>
> First name: John; Second name: Doe; BirthDate: (null)
>
> First name: John; Second name: Doedze; BirthDate: (null)

And I am expecting something like this:

> First name: John; Second name: Doe; BirthDate: (null)
>
> First name: Not specified; Second name: Doe; BirthDate: (null)
>
> First name: Not specified; Second name: Doe; BirthDate: (null)

I understand that in second line GC can not destroy value from firstName, but third call to log method executes after 1-second sleep. I think 1 second is enough time for GC to collect unused strings.

Any idead why "weak" and "copy" attributes can be ignored?
Thanks for help.

Full code:
main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyPerson.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
  @autoreleasepool
  {
     NSString *name = @"John";
     NSMutableString *surname = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Doe"];
     MyPerson *person = [MyPerson createWithFirstName:name secondName:surname];
     [person tellName];

     name = nil;
     [person tellName];
     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
     [surname appendString:@"dze"];
     [person tellName];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

MyPerson.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyPerson : NSObject

@property (weak, getter=getFirstName, setter=setFirstName:) NSString *firstName;
@property (copy, getter=getSecondName, setter=setSecondName:) NSString *secondName;
@property (getter=getBirthDate, setter=setBirthDate:) NSDate *birthDate;

-(void)setFirstName:(NSString *)firstName;
-(NSString *)getFirstName;

-(void)setSecondName:(NSString *)secondName;
-(NSString *)getSecondName;

-(void)setBirthDate:(NSDate *)birthDate;
-(NSDate *)getBirthDate;

-(void) tellName;

+(id)create;
+(id)createWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName;
+(id)createWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName secondName:(NSString *)secondName;
+(id)createWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName secondName:(NSString *)secondName birthDate:(NSDate *)birthDate;

-(id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName secondName:(NSString *)secondName birthDate:(NSDate *)birthDate;

@end
```

MyPerson.m:

```
#import "MyPerson.h"

@implementation MyPerson

@synthesize firstName = m_firstName;
@synthesize secondName = m_secondName;
@synthesize birthDate = m_birthDate;

-(void)tellName
{
  NSMutableString *stringBuilder = [NSMutableString string];
  [stringBuilder appendString:@"First name: "];
  [self appendIfNotNil:self.firstName toBuilder:stringBuilder];
  [stringBuilder appendString:@"; "];
  [stringBuilder appendString:@"Second name: "];
  [self appendIfNotNil:self.secondName toBuilder:stringBuilder];
  [stringBuilder appendString:@"; "];
  [stringBuilder appendString:@"BirthDate: "];
  [stringBuilder appendFormat:@"%@", [m_birthDate     descriptionWithLocale:NSLocaleLanguageDirectionUnknown]];

  NSLog(@"%@", stringBuilder);
}

-(void)appendIfNotNil:(NSString*)str toBuilder:(NSMutableString *)stringBuilder
{
  [stringBuilder appendString:str == nil ? @"Not specified" : str];
}

-(void)setFirstName:(NSString *)firstName
{
  NSLog(@"Setter called for first name: %@", firstName);
  m_firstName = firstName;
}

-(NSString *)getFirstName
{
  NSLog(@"Getter called for first name");
  return m_firstName;
}

-(void)setSecondName:(NSString *)secondName
{
  NSLog(@"Setter called for second name: %@", secondName);
  m_secondName = secondName;
}

-(NSString *)getSecondName
{
  NSLog(@"Getter called for second name");
  return m_secondName;
}

-(id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName secondName:(NSString *)secondName birthDate:(NSDate *)birthDate
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self)
  {
    m_firstName = firstName;
    m_secondName = secondName;
    m_birthDate = birthDate;
  }

  return self;
}

+(id)createWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName secondName:(NSString *)secondName birthDate:(NSDate *)birthDate
{
  MyPerson *person = [MyPerson alloc];
  person = [person initWithFirstName:firstName secondName:secondName birthDate:birthDate];
  return person;
}

+(id)createWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName secondName:(NSString *)secondName
{
  return [MyPerson createWithFirstName:firstName secondName:secondName birthDate:nil];
}

+(id)createWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName
{
  return [MyPerson createWithFirstName:firstName secondName:nil birthDate:nil];
}

+(id)create
{
   return [MyPerson createWithFirstName:nil secondName:nil birthDate:nil];
}


@end
```

Any ideas why "weak" and "copy" attributes can be ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idead why "weak" and "copy" attributes can be ignored? Thanks for help.

They are not ignored. Your tests are flawed.

- To test "weak", you would need to use something other than an NSString, because strings have special memory management. Use an NSObject with no variable reference to it; it will vanish in puff of smoke one line later.

  ```
  self.ob = [NSObject new];
  NSLog(@"%@", self.ob); // nil!
  ```
- To test "copy", you would need to start with an NSMutableString, keep a reference to it, assign it to the property, and then mutate the mutable string; the assigned string would not change, proving that the property is not holding another reference to the same mutable string.
- To test memory management attributes (like `copy`), as well as threading attributes (like `atomic`), do *not* write your own setter! These are instructions to the compiler on how *it* should write the setter (synthesis). If you write the setter manually, you do not get synthesis, and at that point your attributes are meaningless (except insofar as they inform clients of your API).

Comment: The discussion in my book might help you: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_property_memory_management_policies

Comment: And here is example code for testing `weak` - notice that I do not use an NSString! https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk1ch12p348assignWeakRef/ch12p323assignWeakRef/AppDelegate.m

Comment: matt, so if i use "copy" with custom setter, i have to call [parameter copy] manually inside setter? This makes "copy" quite unneccessary.

Comment: Yes, if you write a copy custom setter it is up to _you_ to write the custom setter. Your `@property` attribute settings are only for _synthesized_ setter.

Comment: I'm sorry if my answer failed to grapple with that; I'll add a note to that effect.

Comment: Thank you! I can write my own copy setter, but I can't figure how to write custom setter with weak-reference. Can I use syntesized values, or i have to use my own "private" variable for this purposes?

Comment: "I can write my own copy setter" I'm not so sure you can. Writing a setter is really tricky. Why don't you just let the compiler do it? It knows more than you do! I show code here for adding your own functionality to a synthesized setter: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#EXoverrideaccessor

Comment: matt, writing custom setters is a habit from C++ and Java. And i just want to know, what happens "inside".

Comment: Okay. My book explains how to write your own setter (Chapter 5). But my point is that you _don't_ know what happens "inside". You cannot possibly write an atomic thread-safe setter. How far backwards would you like to go in your explorations? You could turn off ARC and do memory management yourself too. You could ignore all Objective-C 2.0 features and not use property syntax. You could write your code in assembler! Or you could just learn Objective-C as it is _now_. (Or you could learn Swift instead, where none of these issues even exist.)

Comment: Matt, one point of clarification: With ARC, doesn't the auto-generated instance variable have the same memory rules (weak, strong, or unsafe_unretained) as the property, so the weak/strong treatment of the object IS preserved even with a custom setter? (Not so for atomic or copy though.)

Comment: @DuncanC Yes, I tested it and I think you're right. Corrected my answer, with a little better info on testing `weak`.

Comment: That's something I really like about ARC. It use to be that if you wanted properties to take care of object ownership for you you had to use auto-synthesized setter methods. Now with Arc, even instance variables manage weak/strong references with no extra work from the developer. I don't miss having to carefully manage retains/releases/autoreleases!

Comment: @noktigula the `@property` declaration tells the complier how to create a setter. If you make your own setter, the `@property` declaration doesn't do much except help with auto-complete and other niceties within Xcode. Apple's engineering team wrote the compiler, they wrote the operating system, they wrote the language runtime, they designed the CPU and all other other hardware (at least for iOS), and they regularly look for ways to improve how setters work. You can't do it better, your setter will be worse. I create my own setters sometimes, but it should be avoided.

Comment: @DuncanC now that it's easier to use instance variables instead of proper properties with a setter/getter, you should still avoid using instance variables. One of the primary reasons to use a setter/getter is to give yourself flexibility refactoring the code in future. For example imagine a hypothetical NSDate variable that you later change to NSTimeInterval for improved performance. If you used an instance variable you've got to refactor all your code. If you use `@property` you can keep it there, as a custom getter/setter that converts between the old/new data structure.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert, meh. This is style/personal taste rather than a hard fast rule. I tend to use properties for publicly visible attributes of my objects,and instance variables for private/internal attributes. I'll use properties if I know that I need a level of abstraction or need to write a custom getter/setter.